# What does "with" mean here? And is the "which" clause illegal?

Tags: prepositions

Recently I read this sentence from a text book [Differential Games](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486406822) written by a native US professer:

> Small circles indicate that it is P's move, that is, with the minimizing player rests the decision as to which subsequent position.

I am confused about the expression of "with", "as to" and "which". I think "with" should be excluded, "as to" means "concerning" and "which subsequent position" is not a legal clause.

My question:

1. What does "with" mean?
2. Is the "which subsequent position" illegal expression?
3. And what does this sentence mean?

---

Additional context:

> Each position is represented by a circle or rectangle and from each it is possible to go to certain others along the connecting lines in a downward direction. **Small circles indicate that it is P's move, that is, with the minimizing player rests the decision as to which subsequent position.** The squares pertain similarly to E.

The corresponding figure: [image: figure]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The sentence is very poorly written. It means that "it is P's move, that is, the minimizing player makes the decision about the next position." _With_ means 'that is/i.e.'; the expression _which subsequent position_ is sposta make sense to the game player; it appears to be short for 'which subsequent position to move to', if "moving" means anything in the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is an analysis of some strategy game. The OP would do well to append further information about the extract to get a satisfactory answer.At a cursory glance, there's nothing wrong with *"with"* in the sentence (it's merely a case of what they call *pied-piping* in linguistics); *"which"*, however, appears problematic. It should be "*as to **the** subsequent position*" or something like that.

Comment: Isn't it all right to eliminate "with", which leads to "the minimizing player" being the subject? With "with" in the sentence, what is the subject? Could you explain further why "there's nothing wrong with 'with' in the sentence"?

Comment: @zhixin No, because then the verb _rests_ is left stranded. _with_ is the (prepositional) object of the verb _rests._

Comment: @zhixin The sentence could be recast as: _Small circles indicate that it is P's move, that is, the decision as to the next move rests with the minimizing player._ I hope it helps.

Comment: Oh I get it. Thank you! (I didn't realize it is an inverted sentences）